# Two jQuery functions not working in single <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement,

1. on selection of a particular picklist item, I need to show/hide a section with `checkbox`
2. on selection of the checkbox, in step-1, I further need to show/hide another section.

> This is what I tried

```
<script>
j$('#type').on('change', function()
{

    if(this.value == 'Technical Issue'){ 
        j$('#techtroubleshootoption').show();
         j$('#forceemailcase').show();
        j$('#main').hide();
    } 
    else{
        j$('#techtroubleshootoption').hide();
        j$('#forceemailcase').hide();
        j$('#main').show();
    } 
});
j$('#chkforcemailcase').click( function()
{
  if(this.checked){ 
        j$('#techtroubleshootoption').hide();
         j$('#forceemailcase').show();
        j$('#main').show();
    } 
    else{
        j$('#techtroubleshootoption').show();
        j$('#forceemailcase').show();
        j$('#main').hide();
    }   
});
</script>
```

The first function is working and upon selection of a desired values it is showing/hiding section below, but on the selection of checkbox, it is not doing anything.

> Workaround

If a put the **second function** in another `<script>` tag it works **fine**. Now, my question is why it didn't work in the same `<script>` tag and is it the right way to do it to declare multiple `<script>` tags for each function (which  doesn't sound right to me).

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap all of your javascript with `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    j$('#type').on('change', function() {
        if(this.value == 'Technical Issue'){ 
            j$('#techtroubleshootoption').show();
                j$('#forceemailcase').show();
            j$('#main').hide();
        } 
        else{
            j$('#techtroubleshootoption').hide();
            j$('#forceemailcase').hide();
            j$('#main').show();
        } 
        });
        j$('#chkforcemailcase').click( function()
        {
        if(this.checked){ 
            j$('#techtroubleshootoption').hide();
                j$('#forceemailcase').show();
            j$('#main').show();
        } 
        else{
            j$('#techtroubleshootoption').show();
            j$('#forceemailcase').show();
            j$('#main').hide();
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: So, I'm using the script tag at end of page, which is fine right?

Comment: Correct, you will need to first include jQuery, followed by the code posted above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are initializing events, you should do that when the document is ready, not in script tags directly.  script tags are generally a race condition when it comes to elements being available in the DOM while it is being rendered.

Use [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).